# How to delete rows with specific value and modify column values in a 2-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

Putting a very simple example of what I need to do, I have a 2-D array:

```
array([[0, 4],[2, 3],[4, 1],[0, 8],[3, 2],[4, 5],[6, 1],[0, 3],[1, 7],[2, 9]])
```

The first column is time and the other is distance. Being specifically what I have is `[time, distance]`.

For my final array, I need to delete each time=0 and to make continuation of the time. Here is what my final array should be:

```
array([[0, 4],[2, 3],[4, 1],[7, 2],[8, 5],[10, 1],[11, 7],[12, 9]])
```

In this particular case, only `[0, 8]` and `[0, 3]` are deleted because they have time=0.

Also, the previous `[3, 2]` becomes `[7, 2]` given that `4+3=7` (because previous time was 4). Same goes for previous `[4, 5]` becomes `[8, 5]` given that `4+4=8`.Same goes for previous `[6, 1]` becomes `[10, 1]` given that `4+6=10`.

Same goes for previous `[1, 7]` becomes `[11, 7]` given that `10+1=11` (because previous time was 10).
Same goes for previous `[2, 9]` becomes `[12, 9]` given that `10+2=12`.

I am just putting a very small piece of array, thus I need a Python code to do what I just explained.

Comment: Why is the first entry not deleted?

Comment: Because I need the time to start from zero and then on have continuation

Comment: Is your time format military? because if not, some times are gonna exceed 12 and that's problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this short code without the use of any external libraries:

```
array = [[0, 4],[2, 3],[4, 1],[0, 8],[3, 2],[4, 5],[6, 1],[0, 3],[1, 7],[2, 9]]
temp = 0
out = [array[0]]
for i in range(1,len(array)):
    if array[i][0] != 0:
        array[i][0] += temp
        out.append(array[i])
    else:
        temp = array[i-1][0]
print(out)
```

which yields:

```
[out]: [[0, 4], [2, 3], [4, 1], [7, 2], [8, 5], [10, 1], [11, 7], [12, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfect and it is very efficient too. Hope to code like you one day. Best

Answer (score 1):

A slightly faster but pretty much identical approach to @MansourZayer. It is generally preferred to iterate over the items in a list vs. using `range()` and indexing into the list, e.g.

```
In []:
x = [[0, 4],[2, 3],[4, 1],[0, 8],[3, 2],[4, 5],[6, 1],[0, 3],[1, 7],[2, 9]]
t0 = tminus = 0
r = [x[0]]
for t, d in x:
    if t == 0:
        t0 += tminus
        continue
    tminus = t
    r.append([t+t0, d])
r

Out[]:
[[0, 4], [2, 3], [4, 1], [7, 2], [8, 5], [10, 1], [11, 7], [12, 9]]
```